# Rails 4.2 raised ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound when creating a new post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am getting a 'Couldn't find Location with ID=4 for Post with ID=' error within PostsController#create when user creates the new post with nested location form.

In this case, post has one location and user has many locations through posts.

Users can create the first new post successfully, but the error occurs when users create new post again.

PostsController:

```
class Categories::PostsController < ApplicationController
...
 def new   
    @post = Post.new
    if current_user.locations
      @post.location = current_user.locations.first
    else
      @post.build_location
    end
  end

  def create 
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)               
    @post.category = @category              

    if @post.save               
      flash[:success] = "You have succesfully created a new post."              
      redirect_to [@category, @post]                
    else                
      flash[:danger] = "Error occured. Please try again."               
      render :new               
    end             
  end

...

  private 
   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, location_attributes: [:id, :street, :city, :zipcode, :_destroy])
   end
end
```

Here `@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)` in create action throws the error.

I noticed that when I removed `location_attributes: [:id]`, users are able to create new posts. But without whitelisting the location id, the server log has "Unpermitted parameter id" error and also users can't remove the location nested form when editing posts.

I understand that the create method will work by removing:

```
if current_user.locations
   @post.location = current_user.locations.first
```

However, my purpose is to retrieve the previous location data from users so they don't need to put down the same address again in new posts.

**Also, I would like the post can be created without filling out the location form.**

Thank you for your help in advance!

**Update:** 
I have tried changing the association for User, Location, and Post models, but it didn't fix the same error I got.

post.rb

```
belongs_to :location
belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
```

location.rb

```
has_many :posts
belongs_to :user
```

user.rb

```
has_many :posts
has_many :locations
```

What other methods can help fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

This is a situation when your Post should `belong_to` a Location, rather than have `have_one`. This will put a `location_id` foreign key on the the posts table, which should be on the model you're going though, ie `through: posts`.

Currently, when you call `@post.save` in your controller, it will try to query the db for a Post that has not yet been saved to the database, giving you that error.

**post.rb**

```
belongs_to :location
belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
```

**location.rb**

```
has_one :post
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :posts
has_many :locations, through: :posts
```

Lastly, you'll need to add the reference to the db.

```
rails g migration AddLocationRefToPosts location:references
```

Your controller code looks good as far as I can tell and should work after these changes.

Comment: JeffD23, thanks so much for your help! Could you also help explain further why 'Post' in this case should belong to location? If post belongs to location, will it prevent the post from destroying locations when we update post's attributes?

Comment: The Post should belong_to a Location because you need the foreign key on the Post model for the 'User has_many :locations, through: :posts' to work properly. belongs_to and has_one are almost identical, the distinction is where the foreign_key is placed. Updating the post's attributes should not destroy locations unless you specifically tell it to in the controller.

Comment: Sorry, after I change the association relationship between post and location, the same error still exists.

Comment: When I try to create new post after setting 'location has one: post', I got the error "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: locations.post_id: SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."post_id" = ? LIMIT 1"